# WCF Data Services without generated DTO classes

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, n-tier-architecture

I'm planning out my first N-tier architecture and am currently considering how I would best utilize WCF Data Services.  It looks like a good tool except that I'm not thrilled about the client-side's generated data contract classes.  I don't like needing another tool like AutoMapper to then project my modified domain objects into the DTOs before sending the changes back to the server.  It seems that WCF Data Services shouldn't need these generated DTO classes.  It seems feasible that it could instead just provide me a way to send the change tracking information, i.e. the deltas, in a general form back to the server.

Is there in fact a way I can utilize WCF Data Service's change tracking functionality without the client-side's generated DTO classes?

Comment: But if the client is not passing the changes in the DTO, how would your data service know what changed?

Comment: @JericoSandhorn - I clarified the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think to do what you want, you would have to implement the OData REST protocol yourself on the client side, for instance using Atom XML or JSON (both supported).

But if your are open to it, I would suggest you consider using basic WCF Data Contracts and Service contracts and define your own perfect service interface between tiers instead of coupling it too closely to your data model. Microsoft makes it easy to expose your Entity model to other tiers for rapid development, but this can have some serious downsides. For instance, changing your Entity model can cause undesirable upward changes through the other tiers. My team started out that way and quickly ran into issues, so in the end we elected to spend more time on defining the exact contracts between tiers, modeling our business objects and then implementing the DB persistence in what ever way we wanted. For instance, we moved away from the Entity Framework, and switched to Dapper.NET without having to change other clients of the service.

Even with WCF Data Contracts, you may still end up generating client side contracts when you create service references to your service. But you can avoid that by sharing your Data Contract DLL so the client and server have exactly the same class and no duplication. I would only recommend that if your projects are all under the same SDLC.

One of the tradeoffs you will have to decide on is a choice between maintaining translations of data objects across tiers for flexibility, or coupling all of your tiers tightly on the same exact model using less code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [WCF Proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285939/what-are-wcf-proxies-and-what-are-they-good-for), it helps to build wcf services without DTO..

see this example : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786601/Ways-to-generate-proxy-for-WCF-Service