# WCF data service custom implementation

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

How to pass parameters from client to method in server in order to get entity data.

At Server side :

```
List<Foo> getFoos = _serverObject.GetFoos(p1, p2); //Here's how I am getting foo from another server

class FooProvider
{ 
   public IQueryable<Foo> Foos
   {
      get{return getFoos.AsQueryable();}
   }
}
```

At Client Side :

```
var res = from f in ctx.Foos
          where f.p1 == p1_val && f.p2 == p2_val
          select f;
```

Now what I am trying to get is all Foo record depend on `p1_val` and `p2_val` parameters, but I would have to pass it to `_serverObject.GetFoos(p1, p2)`; so that the `p1` and `p2` are set from client not from the server.

Please suggest some mechanism

Comment: in OData service you need to have your entity context first then you can apply filter on it and get the data at client side. But as I understand correctly your context data is depended on the filter parameters.. It can be easily implemented if you consider another service for parameter

Comment: I think it should be possible with single service as client is giving the queryable expression to server and from that it should load the parameters. Isn't it??

Comment: You would need to pass a predicate. Look at the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299534/linq-passing-lambda-expression-as-parameter-to-be-executed-and-returned-by-meth

Comment: That's my problem also with OData service that I cant use predicate as expression is implemented on client side on context rather than passing expression from client to server then implementing it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe what you try to achieve is mostly related to

[Using an ADO.NET Entity Framework DataSource(WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728280(v=vs.110).aspx)

and passing a parameter from client to server is only the tip of the iceberg however if I am wrong and all your problems will be resolved by only passing complex types p1, and p2 from client to server then do the following:

1. In your WCF server simply define 2 new [Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733811(v=vs.110).aspx) and call them p1 and p2 with all your desired fields
2. Now on the client side when you add a service reference to the newly created service, you will be able to populate p1 and p2 and pass them to your server from your [Proxy class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285939/proxies-in-wcf-what-are-they-what-are-they-good-for) when you call your service method

Moral of the story:
You need to define those two types in your service as Data Contracts so you can use them as parameter in your proxy class on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does OData supports DataContract? Conceptually I agree with you but I doubt in its implementation. I will test and let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: Have a look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802285/can-we-convert-odata-metadata-to-c-sharp-code-datacontract

Comment: Thanks again, I have now the data from metadata at client side, but how should I pass this to server as Odata service does not have any service contract and operation contract. Should I use [webget]?

Comment: Could you please give some small implementation at client side.

Comment: I don't know which kind of binding you will use to access your service however I would consider you want to make your WCF service restful which consequently means you will be able to access it through a browser and you would need to annotate your get methods with that [webget] attributes. If that is going to be the case then follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728279(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Problem now solved, I have to make properties in provider class and then I just have to map the parameters to that properties which I get from [WebGet] method. I am marking your solution as an Answer as it led me to the solution which I need. Thanks a lot!! :) Though I will put full solution of mine, may it will be helpful to others.